# Bringing isw*() ctype functions to Mac OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql, ctype

tsvector field in my Postgres database is not being populated with Arabic text on my Mac OS X (10.8.2). It's perfectly working with English text.

I asked over IRC and I was told perhaps the platform I'm using doesn't have isw*() ctype functions that work with those encoding and ctype settings.

So I tried on a Debian 6 (32-bit) and the tsvector field was populated normally.

What can I do to bring this functionality to OS X?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The functions `iswalnum()` etc are available on Mac OS X (10.7.5 officially, but I'd be more than astonished to find them missing on 10.8.2).  So the reason given on IRC doesn't make a lot of sense.  There might be issues with locale; does the code use `setlocale()` or use the `_l`-suffix functions (plus `getlocale()`)?  There might be a problem with whether the functions support the locale you're using; which locale is it?  What are the environment variables `$LC_ALL` or `$LC_CTYPE` set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix-style locale support on OS X is pretty broken.  Even if you set a UTF-8 locale, it's not going to do anything useful with that.  So OS X is probably not going to be a good platform for running your application.